# Navbar position issues to resolution

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, resolution

I'm trying to design a simple website
and whenever I check the different resolutions for my page, the menu bar
keeps re-adjusting its position below the "Contact for Services" section.

Is there some way to fix the position whenever the browser width changes so it doesn't drop down when the size changes?

I'm trying to get the page to look like this:

http://postimg.org/image/emr6eh63h/

**HTML**

```
<body>
<!-- ############### -->
<!-- OVERALL WRAPPER -->
<!-- ############### -->
<div class="head_wrapper">
    <!-- HeaderBarMain -->
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Contact for services questions on: ####</h2>
        <!-- Contact Information -->
        <!--<div class="contact">-->
        <!-- </div><!-- END contact -->
        <!-- Navigation menu -->
        <div class="navMain">
        <!-- Menu List -->
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- END navMain -->
    </div><!-- END header -->
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.head_wrapper {
    width:100%;
}
.header {
    background: #717171;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:0px;
}
.navMain {
    float:right;
    margin:15px 50px 28px 0px;
}
.navMain ul {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.navMain ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
}
.navMain ul li a {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.navMain ul li a:hover {
}
.header h2 {
    margin: 20px 30px 5px 440px;
    font-size:12px;
    float:left;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: do you want keep a fluid grid?

Answer (score 0):

If you want `nav` not to drop just give `head_wrapper` a `min-width: 960px` so that container may not collapse inner elements.

```
 .head_wrapper {
    min-width:960px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Issue with your code is you are giving `.header h2` margin-left: 440px that is pushing the nav to drop. `head_wrapper` is container which has width `100%` i.e. is dependent on screen size. When you resize screen size inner elements are static in `px` they get compact due to lack of space. Just give the container a static width. **OR** if you want to make fluid i.e. responsive, then don't use `px` and add [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to your css and see [how to create a responsive navbar](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/).

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xpj75/)**

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your nav-bar to stretches I would recommend to not use %

```
http://jsfiddle.net/dgrxU/
```

in that example I just changed the head-wrapper width to 1024 pixels, same for header

if you want to manage the size for different devices or screen resolutions you can use media queries

```
http://mediaqueri.es
```

hope this can help you

PD: I don't know why the system is not allowing me to add hyperlinks, sorry about that